# The title of Open Source should be changed to Open License

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, site-promotion, site-name

The current name of this site is "Open Source" the current scope of this site is 80% licensing and maybe 20% open source. The current name does not fully depict what this site answers.

As your answer please suggest alternate names that you think would better suit this site.

Please voice your agreement/disagreement, and propose alternate names as well.

Comment: I'll say "Absolutely, yes!" if and only if we *want* all the questions to be about licensing, which I know isn't 100% true (though true for many).

Comment: I'm not sure why people are closing this as *primarily opinion-based*, but this is a question that **wants** your opinion. The purpose of meta is to encourage discussion, and hear the community's thoughts.

Comment: This question needs to be open so that the opinion of the community can be displayed as votes.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree. With a scope that is ever changing, it is pre-mature to request name changes.

Not all questions on this site will be about licensing. One of the main focuses, which sadly isn't coming to life fast enough, is the organization and marketing of projects.

If we continue to broaden the scope, the name change would be detrimental to the site's development. I'm against this 100%. If we should considered a name change (which I don't recommend in any case), there should be thinking behind it so it is accepting of all topics. Right now, if I had to recommend something, it would be Open Info.SE But now is not the time.

Answer (score 4):

Open License would be a different site. Anyone who wishes to see an openlicence.SE can propose it on Area 51. The site we are presently building is opensource.SE and that is not subject to change.

Answer (score -11):

Proposal Name

The name of Open Source should be changed to Open License. This name better suits the types of questions answered on this site.